# async.each will not working in callback functions

Tags: node.js

I have an object of objects we can iterate that object.Each object will working on functions sequential. first function callback comes then second function working.Second function callback comes iterating next object.

Appliction working on `node.js`

we can use `async.each` but will not working properly.

```
 async.each(result,function(item,callback){
  keys1 ='id'
  keys2 ='resul'
  var key1value = item[keys1]
  var key2value = item[keys2]
  var query = '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"' + keys1 + ':' + key1value + ' AND ' + keys2 + ':' + key2value + '"}},"sort":{"_id":{"order":"asc"}}}'
  client.search({ index: config.indexname, type: config.basetype, body:   query }).then(function (data) {
         if(err){
           callback(err);
           return;
           }else{
            if (data.hits.hits.length == 0) {
               client.index({ index: config.indexname, type:config.basetype, body: data.hits.hits }, function (err, results) {
                    console.log("Inserted data");
                    callback("inserted");
                });
             } else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                var rows={}
                rows=result[i];
                rows._catalogId = data.hits.hits[0]._source._catalogId;
                rows._connectionId =data.hits.hits[0]._source._connectionId;
                rows._dataImportId =data.hits.hits[0]._source._dataImportId;
                var param = { index: config.indexname, type: config.basetype, id: data.hits.hits[0]._id, body: { doc:rows, doc_as_upsert: true } };
                client.update(param, function (err, results) {
                    console.log("updated data");
                    callback("updated");
                  });
              }
          }

     });
 });
```

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: Manan, plz help me.

Comment: seems like error is this `var key1value = result[0]['id']
  var key2value = result[0]['resul']` it should be `var key1value = item['id']
  var key2value = item['resul']`

Comment: Mudaser, sorry by my mistake I am edited the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [async API for each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), you will see it says

> Note, that since this function applies iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

So the objects are not being worked on sequentially.